# .git folder of iOS project

Tags: ios, git

I use git to manage my ios project, and as we know git would generate a .git folder under the project, I want to know when I upload the app to app store using Xcode, should I remove .git folder first ? Or would .git folder be archived into app when upload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.git` folder is not included in your app archive.  You should not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your code and create a bundle, it never has git folder contents in it. git is just an alternate to svn. It doesn't matters to app bundle whether you have .git file in your project or not. That won't affect your bundle at all. In short you **don't** need to delete this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code and your .git folder is never uploaded to AppStore. Only the compiled app bundle will be uploaded.

That is, you don't have to delete your .git folder.

Answer (score -2):

you may open a Terminal, then type:

```
ls -A
```

you can found all files, include the hidden file ".git"

want to delete it, type:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: Bad advice. What's the point of using git in a project if you're going to delete its files?